# golang + mongodb: sanitize input

Tags: mongodb, go, trim

I would like to verify the users' input before inserting it into the database. With this trim function, I can check whether the input was empty was empty or not.

```
if len(strings.Trim(r.Form.Get("firstName"), " ")) == 0 {
```

But I would like also to detect messages like these:

```
"username": {"$ne": null}
```

I tried stuff `like if len(strings.Trim(r.Form.Get("firstName"), " $/^\")) == 0 {`, but always get errors concerning the signs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, it seems that it's better to use `strings.TrimSpace` https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace to trim white space, it covers more cases. Second, it's not clear what you mean when you're speaking about sanitizing messages like that: `"username": {"$ne": null}`. Do you want to get rid of all characters like `":{$}` and make it like `username ne null`? But in that case you still have the length greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash in order to get rid of error.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    firstName := " ^$/  Hans \\ ^$  "
    sanitizedName := strings.Trim(firstName, " $/^\\")
    fmt.Println(sanitizedName)
}
```

Output:

```
Hans
```

Comment: also, you can use a raw string literal `` which makes an escape character unnecessary.

Comment: what about sanitizing against other db operations like db.dropDatbase() ?